# まったりとしてそれでいてしつこさがなく Pop culture phrase

Tags: expressions

I'm seeking help translating a phrase that appears in a video game, which seems to be a pop culture reference. My research on this implies it may originate from Oishinbo, but I was unable to confirm this. The line appears in an old Famicom game about a SWAT team liberating hostages from terrorists. The particular line is as follows:

まったりとして　それでいて

しつこさがなく・・・うーん

いいしごとを　している

The phrase itself appears to have a meme-like quality, as seen from these images.

[image]

[image]

Your input appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked up each word in a dictionary? What have you found so far?

Comment: The  meaning of the phrase is none too complicated (I think), if you know the basic grammar of Japanese and the meaning of the individual words.  How it applies in the context in which it was uttered is quite another thing though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Judging intuitively, it seems that the phrase on the shirt is designed only for jeu de mots or without knowing much meaning.

"まったり" is a word expressing a certain kind of taste or flavor in the Kansai dialect. It is a word close to "コクがある", but not exactly the same, which is a compliment for the taste. According to the dictionary "コクがある" is defined as "rich in flavor".

"しつこい" means "persistent" and when it is used for the taste or flavor it means "too heavy or too rich in flavor", so "しつこくない" means literally "it isn't too heavy in flavor" or "it isn't too rich in flavor".

The taste or flavor which is "まったりしている" and also "しつこくない" sounds contradictory. So I judged that the designer doesn't know much about the meaning of words or he/she is only playing a word game.

## EDIT

多くのコメントへの返答として、

コメントありがとうございます。

> まったりとしていて、それでいてしつこさがない。

まったりしているけれどまったりさが持っているあの「ねとっ」としたあるいは「もちっ」とした若干重みのある感じがない。 深くて、濃くて、そして軽い。
漫画の作者が究極の美味しい味の一つとして考えだした自慢の表現だと思います。
そんな味は出せないからこそ、値打ちのある表現であり、値打ちのある味なのだと思います。あくまでも架空の話として。また、あくまでも食べ物の味として。
改めてインターネットで調べますとチョコレートやチーズでこの表現が打ってつけの味が出せているものがあるようですので、漫画上の架空の話というのは言い過ぎです。

goldbrickさんのコメントにある
「まったりしている」と「しつこくない」の（表面上の）相反は「それでいて」によって明確に言及されています。これはこの文句の創作者がそれぞれの言葉の意味を知っていると示唆するものです。
は、そのとおりだと私も思います。 むしろ、それぞれの意味を完全に知って使ったと思います。

いつの間にか「まったり」が若い人の間で本来の関西弁である「まったり」が持っていたものと違う意味で使われはじめ、ネットの勢いで一気に広まり、その土壌の上で、漫画で使われたセリフそのものがシャツやバッグのデザインで流用され、広まり、更に質問者が紹介したゲームでも使われているというのが実情なのでしょう。
ここでは、最初にこの表現を考えた漫画の作者の意図とは無関係に言葉が一人歩きしています。

実情を見ますと、まさに質問者がmeme-likeという言葉で表現している通りです。

言葉は生き物ですので使われるうちに最初の持っている意味と違ってもかまいません。
しかし、meme-likeに使われているからといって、本来の意味から考えると座りの悪い使われ方を見て、変だなと思うのは思わない人より健康であると思うのですがどうですか。
作者自身、「まったり」だが「しつこくない」という連結は同居しにくい（座りが悪い）かもしれないと思ったからこそ、そして、座り悪さを承知の上で思い切って使ったからこそ、その後のシャツのデザイン等へも流用したくなるような見事な表現として評価されmeme-likeに拡散していったのだと思います。
もとの意味（漫画の作者が編み出した時に本当はあり得ない組み合わせの表現だとご本人が思っていただろうと言う意味）を知った上で、味の表現とは別のところで使っているなら（ほんのジョークとして言葉遊びをしているので）いざ知らず、知っていないならその人を「言葉を知らずに使っている」と言っても問題なしだと思います。

私の答えの最初に記述した、シャツの上の文言を見ての直感的理解:
"Judging intuitively, it seems that the phrase on the shirt is designed only for jeu de mots or without knowing much meaning."
はこのような感想を素直に記したものです。

Comment: 文章としてはその2つをほどよいところで両立させてるのが評価に値するってことじゃないかと思います．

Comment: `... sounds contradictory.... the designer doesn't know much about the meaning of words or he/she is only playing a word game.` -- でも... 「まったりとしていて、それでいてしつこくない」は、もとは漫画「美味しんぼ」の有名な台詞なんですよね？　漫画の中でも意味のない単なる言葉遊びだったのでしょうか。。。

Comment: Yoshさんと私とで評価が分かれるということはコピーの作者としては狙いどおり成功なのでしょうね。

Comment: @Chocolate：美味しんぼのセリフとシャツのコピーとは別物とするべきだと思います。美味しんぼの作者は味の求道をテーマとしておりますので、求める味の表現として考え出したのでしょうから問題なしでしょうね。だからと言って、シャツの表現の評価尺度に使うのは少し筋違いだと思います。

Comment: @mackygoo この言葉を全くご存じなかったようですが、多少ネットスラングに詳しい日本人なら間違いなく何度も聞いたことがある台詞です。というか質問者も自分で頑張って調べてそこまでは理解した上で質問しているのです。Tシャツは「ほら、こんな風に名ゼリフとして日本人に認知されてるでしょ」という証拠の意味で貼られているに過ぎないので、その意味をマジレスしようとしても意味ないです。

Comment: `別物とするべき` -- いやでもOPはちゃんと「it may originate from **Oishinbo** 」って書いてるし、それをわかった上で、`seeking help translating a phrase that appears in a video game`（シャツじゃなくて） **ゲーム**に出てくるフレーズ、「まったりとしてそれでいてしつこさがなく・・・うーんいいしごとをしている」っていう文を訳したい、って言ってるんでしょ？　(←美味しんぼにしてもゲームにしても、ちゃんと質問読んではります？？)　ゲームの中でも意味ないかどうかわかるんですか？

Comment: ①「まったりしている」と「しつこくない」の（表面上の）相反は「それでいて」によって明確に言及されています。これはこの文句の創作者がそれぞれの言葉の意味を知っていると示唆するものです。②「Ｘ、それでいてＹ」は、ＸとＹは対立する（併存が難しい）ようではあるが、特定のものにおいて実際に併存している、ということを表す（特に珍しくない）修辞的パターンです。③あなた自身「まったり」は「rich in flavor」と類義、そして「しつこくない」は「not too rich in flavor」という意味だと説明なさっています。 これを基に文句を訳せば「rich in flavor, but not too rich in flavor」となります。（さらにこれを「rich in flavor」を「まったりとしている」に置き換えて逆翻訳すると「まったりとしていて、それでいてまったりとしすぎていない。」となります。）これのどこがおかしいのでしょうか。

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems clear that the meaning is something along the line of "It's rich in flavor, but not too rich." When the words are taken on their own I suppose it's not that hard to decipher the meaning. I was over-thinking it a bit due to its seemingly idiomatic nature. Phrases such as this sometimes have well known translations/meanings.

Comment: ①「the phrase ... is designed ... 」と「[designer] is only playing a word game」という言い方からは、「designer」はオリジナルのフレーズの考案者（「美味しんぼ」の作者）のことを指すものだと受け取られるのですが（フレーズを設計したのは「美味しんぼ」の作者ですし、（仮にフレーズが「ただの言葉遊び」だとすれば）「ただの言葉遊び」をしている/いたのもその作者です。）、本当はTシャツのデザイナーのことを指していたのでしょうか。もしそうなら少なくとも（つまり考え方ではなくとも）書き方に修正が必要だと思います。②このフレーズを使ったテキストは「古いファミコンのゲーム」に登場したものなので、インターネットが功績を主張できるかは怪しいところです。③仮に「まったりとしていてしつこさがない」なら座りが悪いといえるでしょう。しかし実際の文句は「まったりとしていて、それでいてしつこさがない」です。「それでいて」という論理的連結語によって座りの悪さは解消されています。このフレーズ全体の意味がどのように成り立っているかは平均的日本語話者なら理解できます。これは意味をなさない唯の言葉遊びではありません。きわめて合理的な日本語です。

Comment: あなたの『「まったりとしている」と「しつこさがない」は相反するように思われる。だからフレーズの創作者/そのフレーズを再利用する人は、これらの言葉の意味を知らないのだと判断する。』という主張は破綻しています。あなたは元々は意味論上の話をしていて、フレーズの起源や創作者の意図や、再利用者たちがそれらを知っているかどうかは全く関係ないはずなのですが。

Answer (score 3):

Yes 「まったりとしていて、それでいてしつこくない」 is a famous phrase usually used to (jokingly) describe the taste of a dish. Actually, this is so famous that people would use it without even understanding the origin. This phrase is obviously puzzling and counterintuitive if you try to interpret this seriously, but its oxymoronic quality is exactly what made this phrase famous.

It's widely believed that this phrase is from the Japanese cooking comic 美味しんぼ, but I could not **confirm** this, either. From what I could google, it's possible that no one actually said this phrase verbatim in the original manga. So it may be better to understand this as "a typical 美味しんぼ-ish phrase which caught on in isolation from 美味しんぼ". You may already have seen this, but [there was a person](http://www.shibatashoten.co.jp/dayori/2012/06/21_1542.html) who tried to identify the first usage of this.

> ちなみに83年から連載が始まった『美味しんぼ』では「まったり」は早くも１巻第2話で登場します。フォワグラを食べた栗田さんの「まったりとこくのある味が口の中にとろけるようにひろがって…そしてこの香り…」という感想でした。「まったりとしていてそれでいて少しもしつこくない」っていうのが決めゼリフのように知られていますが、どの辺の話に出てくるのでしょう。３巻第３話でスッポンを食べた栗田さんは「こってりとしていて、それで少しもくどくないのね、それにこの舌ざわり」と述べていましたが…。もっとも私は初めのほうの巻をちょっと眺めただけでして、どなたか108巻分チェックして初出をお教えください。

Translating this phrase is way beyond my English ability, so I'll leave it to someone else. Basically both まったり and しつこい refer to the same kind of deep flavor that slowly spreads and lasts in the mouth for a while (typically that of an oily dish), but しつこい sounds negative. Anyway, if you are fine with free translation, it may be better to replace it with some well-known funny phrase used in cooking shows in the English-speaking cultures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish I knew the context for this within the game. You may be right that this turn of phrase is being used metaphorically in some way. I'm going to translate it literally for now. Hopefully the context will become clear when someone is able to test out the game.

Comment: @Playongo Oh, so this line does not necessarily describe a work of the SWAT team itself :) Then you I think you have to translate literally for now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be looking for a literal translation.

> まったりとして　それでいて
>   しつこさがなく・・・うーん
>   いいしごとをしている

One could literally translate it this way, particularly in a food-related context:

> It's rich in taste/flavor, and yet,
>   It has no hint of heaviness... hmm
>   They're doing an excellent job.

Some words have more than one meaning. To break it down to smaller chunks, with alternative translations:

> まったりとして -- rich, mellow, full-bodied in taste/flavor; relaxed, chilled out
>   それでいて -- and yet; despite that; but for all that; but at the same time
>   しつこさがなく -- has no heaviness; is not heavy (at all); not persistent; not too loud
>   うーん -- hmm
>   いいしごとをしている -- doing a good/great/excellent job/work.